# How do you search for all Advanced PDF Templates

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

What is the correct record type for searching for Advanced PDF Template records in netsuite. The following does not work:

```
search.create({
    type: 'advancedpdftemplate',
    columns: ['scriptid'],
    filters: [['scriptid', 'is', 'somescriptid'], 'AND', ['isinactive', 'is', 'F']]
}).run().each(function (r) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Don't see anything in the help topic for record.Type (note the small r in the title). Some code referencing/using them is in the help for the N/render Module.

Comment: I do see it in query.Type as PDF_TEMPLATE pdftemplate which is what also appears in the URL when editing a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is not a scriptable record. I reached out to Marty Zigman and this was his response:

```
Running this:
  nsapiGetRecord('pdftemplate')

indicates this: 
  {initializedefaults: Array(23), transformdefaults: Array(23), 
  id: "pdftemplate", type: "OTHER", scriptable: false, …}
```